# What is the weather probability?

Tags: probability

I checked similar threads and understood one thing from them, but I need some help with this problem.

"A newspaper presents the weather in this form. Linn, Maria and Victoria discuss the weather that's going to happen tomorrow":

Weather : Chance(%)

Rain : 40%
Cloudy : 70%
Hail : 10%
Storm : 5%
Strong wind : 40%

Maria says that the risk of a storm and hail is 15%.
Linn says that the chance of it not raining is 60%.
Victoria says the weather form is wrong because the sum of all the chances is larger than 100%.

"How do the girls think ?, Does anyone think wrong about the weather ?"

So here's what I've done: I know that the probability of the hail and storm is: 0,1*0,05 = 0,005 = 0,5%

How do I calculate the chance of it not raining, and does Victoria think right ?

Comment: Victoria is wrong. The events are  not mutually exclusive. It might be wind and hail and rain and cloudy together in any combinations.Thus probability of hail and storm is not $0.01*0.05$.

Comment: Wait a minute, so Victoria is wrong that the sum doesn't need to add up to 100%, but you wrote "the probability of hail and storm is not 0.01 * 0.05". First off, do you mean 0.1 instead of 0.01 ? Because I wrote that it was a 10% chance of hail. Second, do you mean that Maria is actually wrong ? Or is my brain just shutting off right now ?

Comment: Victoria and Maria  are wrong. Victoria assumed that the event are mutually exclusive. Maria just makes the summation of probabilities of stopm and hail that is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maria is certainly wrong, since the chance of a storm and hail is at most the chance of a storm (5%). Linn is right. Victoria is wrong, the events are not mutually exclusive.

I would certainly not assume independence here.

Answer (score 0):

Maria is right only if we assume that the events are independent: in this case, the probability of hail and storm is $0.1\cdot 0.05=0.005=0.5\%$.

Linn is right: the chance of it not raining is $1-0.4=0.6=60\%$.

Victoria is wrong: as correctly stated in the comments, the events are not mutually esclusive and the sum of probabilities is not necessary $1$.